# Bacakend Image not fully loaded in <img> tag in Angular app

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, web

I am trying to create an Angular Reactive Form where when you upload an image it automatically adds it to the backend and returns the url to the image which is stored in form data

the url returned is loaded by and  tag to show the image uploaded.

this  tag is not fully loading the image and I dont know where is the problem, because the image is loading perfectly when I open the backend link in a new tab. Also, sometimes I get a error like `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200 (OK)`

IMAGE EXAMPLES:

[image: partial image displayed]
[image: CONTENT_LENGTH error]

Html :

```
<!-- Name Form -->
<div class="input-group form-group mt-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Employee ID</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" [attr.disabled]="true" class="form-control" formControlName="emp_id">
</div>

<!-- Employee ID Form -->
<div class="input-group form-group mt-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Entry Number</span>
  </div>
  <input id="entry_num" [attr.disabled]="true" formControlName="entry_num" class="form-control" readonly>
</div>

<!-- Accompany Form -->
<div class="input-group form-group mt-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Number of people accompanying the Visitor</span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" min="1" required [class.is-invalid]="accompany.invalid && accompany.touched"
    class="form-control" formControlName="accompany">
</div>
<small class="text-danger" *ngIf="accompany.invalid && accompany.touched">Number is Required</small>
<small class="text-danger" *ngIf="entryUpdate.controls['accompany'].value<1 && accompany.touched">Number should be
  positive</small>

<!-- Pass ID Form -->
<div class="input-group form-group mt-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Pass ID assigned to Visitor</span>
  </div>
  <input type="number" min="1" required [class.is-invalid]="pass_id.invalid && pass_id.touched" class="form-control"
    formControlName="pass_id">
</div>
<small class="text-danger" *ngIf="pass_id.invalid && pass_id.touched">Pass ID is Required</small>
<small class="text-danger" *ngIf="entryUpdate.controls['pass_id']?.value<1 && pass_id.touched">Number should be
  positive</small>

<!-- Entry Time Form -->
<div class="form-group input-group mt-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend pr-4">
    <span class="input-group-text">Time of Entry</span>
  </div>
  <ngb-timepicker formControlName="entry_time" required></ngb-timepicker>
</div>

<!-- Add Image -->
<div>
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
  </label>
  <input type="file" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" id="file-upload">
</div>

<div class="media" *ngIf="entryUpdate.controls['image'].value">
  <div class="media-left">
    <img class="media-object" [attr.src]="entryUpdate.controls['image'].value" alt="entry image">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Remark Form -->
<div class="input-group form-group mt-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Remarks</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="remarks">
</div>

<!-- Submit button -->
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button id="submit" [disabled]="entryUpdate.invalid" class="btn btn-primary float-right"
      type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

typescript :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { GuardService } from 'src/app/services/guard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-entry',
  templateUrl: './entry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./entry.component.css']
})
export class EntryComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private guardService: GuardService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  // variables
  entryUpdate = this.fb.group({
    emp_id: [''],
    entry_num: [''],
    accompany: ['', Validators.required],
    pass_id: ['', Validators.required],
    entry_time: [{ hour: 8, minute: 0 }, Validators.required],
    image: ['', Validators.required],
    remarks: ['']
  })

  submitted: boolean = false;
  errMsg: string = null;
  message: string = null;

  // form functions
  get accompany() { return this.entryUpdate.get('accompany'); }
  get pass_id() { return this.entryUpdate.get('pass_id'); }
  get entry_time() { return this.entryUpdate.get('entry_time'); }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // accompany, pass_id
    this.entryUpdate.controls['emp_id'].setValue(parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("emp_id")));
    this.entryUpdate.controls['entry_num'].setValue(parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("entry_num")));

    this.submitted = false
  }

  onFileSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', <File>event.target.files[0])

    const emp_id = this.entryUpdate.controls['emp_id'].value
    const entry_num = this.entryUpdate.controls['entry_num'].value

    this.guardService.createImage(formData, emp_id, entry_num)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log("sucess in adding image")
      }, err => {
        console.error(`error occored in image upload : ${err}`)
      })

    const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
      'image/png': 'png',
      'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
      'image/jpg': 'jpg'
    }

    const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[event.target.files[0].type];
    const path = this.guardService.getImagePath(`${emp_id}-${entry_num}.${ext}`)
    this.entryUpdate.controls['image'].setValue(path);
    // const img = document.getElementById('imgPath') as HTMLImageElement;
    // img.src = path.toString + '?' + new Date().getTime();
    // console.warn(path.toString + '?' + new Date().getTime());
  }

  onSubmit() {

    this.submitted = true;

    // changing the "entry_time" attribute to a string
    var time = this.entryUpdate.controls['entry_time'].value;
    var hour = (time.hour).toString().padStart(2, "0");
    var min = (time.hour).toString().padStart(2, "0");
    this.entryUpdate.controls['entry_time'].setValue(`${hour}-${min}`)

    // clearing space
    time = hour = min = null;

    console.warn(this.entryUpdate.value);

    // updatingting entry
    this.guardService.onEntry(this.entryUpdate.value)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.message = "Updation Sucessful";
      }, err => {
        this.errMsg = err.statusText;
      });
  }

  reset() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  goBack() {
    this.router.navigate(['guardDash']);
  }

}
```

backend:

```
//Get image to show
router.get('/image/:img', async (req, res) => {
    // Access the provided 'page' and 'limt' query parameters
    let img = req.params.img;
    let imgPath = `../../assets/${img}`

    const imgUrlPath = path.join(__dirname, imgPath)

    res.sendFile(imgUrlPath);
});

//post and save image to show
router.post('/image/:emp_id/:entry_num', multerImage, async (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file
    if (file) {
        res.status(200).json("image added");
    } else {
        res.status(500).json("image problem");
    }
})
```

multer middleware :

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
}

// storage management of the upload file
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, './backend/assets');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {

        // extension
        const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];

        // Access the provided 'page' and 'limt' query parameters
        let emp_id = req.params.emp_id;
        let entry_num = req.params.entry_num;
        let nameImg = `${emp_id}-${entry_num}.${ext}`

        cb(null, nameImg);
    }
});

// var upload = multer({ storage: storage }); 

module.exports = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');
```

<----EDIT---->

When I put a random image URL instead of my dynamic back end image link in the  tag, the image was loaded perfectly every time?? what could be the problem??

Comment: Your back-end sets wrong `Content-Length` header for that file.

Comment: How to set that??

Comment: Your lib that is responsible for sending files adds that for you. Maybe check issues of that lib?